# MYSQL query to find available venues?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
venue (name, venue_id, capacity etc)
venue_booking (venue_id and date_booked)
```

I have inputs for the date the user wants to book a venue ($date).

How can I find if a venue is available to book on the $date that’s is not already booked in the venue_booking table?

How to only find available venues on the date?

Answer (score 1):

sql supports `NOT IN` operator:

```
select *
from venue
where venue_id not in (
    select venue_id
    from venue_booking
    where date_booked=$date)
```

don't forget that

1. date_booked should be date columns, without time component
2. date literals should be presented in quotes, like

like:

```
where date_booked = '2016-10-20'
```

also, you might need [date function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date.asp)

Comment: @jack this query 100% works, probably you have some other errors

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM venue v
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM venue_booking
    WHERE venue_id = v.venue_id
    AND date_booked = 'date_value' -- change date_value accordingly
);
```

### **<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d3651/2)</kbd>**

Comment: @jack : Is there any rows in `venue_booking` table?

Comment: Check whether the date in where condition is same as the date in venue_booking table